# Group duplicate entries in an array without the use of hash_map

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, std, stdvector

Given an array of elements (including duplicates), I want identify all distinct entries and print their corresponding frequencies into another array. For example:

```
Input: 3,9,1,2,3,8,13,7,2,9,20,7,4,5,13,1,5,6,2,5,20,13,3,5,6

Output: Sorted unique array: 
        1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 13 20
        Sorted unique array element frequency: 
        2 3 3 1 4 2 2 1 2 3 2
```

I have a code that does this using unordered_map, but I want to know the most performance efficient way to tackle this using std::vector, std::sort, std::unique etc. Following is the code I presently have that uses std::vector:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int counter=1;

    std::vector<int> arr1 {3,9,1,2,3,8,13,7,2,9,20,7,4,5,13,1,5,6,2,5,20,13,3,5,6};
    std::vector<int> arr2;

    sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());

    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr1.begin() ; it != arr1.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)(arr1.size()-1); i++)
    {
         if (arr1[i] == arr1[i+1]) {
             do {
                  counter++;
                  i++;
             } while(i<(int)arr1.size() && (arr1[i] == arr1[i+1]));
             arr2.push_back(counter);
             counter=1;
         } else
             arr2.push_back(1);
    }

    arr1.erase( unique( arr1.begin(), arr1.end() ), arr1.end() );
    printf("Sorted unique array: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr1.begin() ; it != arr1.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    assert(arr1.size() == arr2.size());
    printf("Sorted unique array element frequency: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr2.begin() ; it != arr2.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
 }
```

Presently my code uses 2 passes: pass1- A for loop over entire arr1 to calculate arr2, pass2: std::unique + std::erase to obtain all the distinct entries in arr1.

Is there a more performance efficient way of tackling this, say doing it in 1 pass, without the use of hash_map/unordered_map's?

Comment: TL;DR; `std::sort()`?

Comment: If you are fine with two additional arrays, one for unique elements and one for frequencies, then it's easy to compute both in a single pass over sorted `arr1`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik:  Since my actual code shall have millions of entries, I want to accomplish the single pass without adding extra memory (of additional arrays). If there is a way to handle this using only arrays's arr1 and arr2, that would be the best.

Comment: Well, you could essentially re-implement `std::unique` algorithm, and compact `arr1` while calculating frequencies at the same time. You need two iterators into `arr1` - the "normal" one incremented on every iteration, and the "free spot" one you increment only when you encounter the first of a run of equal elements. As you iterate, you copy each new unique element to "free spot" and advance it; you skip over repeated elements while counting them. At the end, "free spot" iterator would be suitable to pass to `erase()`

Comment: This might be a good, advanced, interview coding questions.  Lots of opportunity for candidate to make, then correct, off-by-1 and fencepost errors ...

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: not quite sure I understand how I can implement 2 iterators within 'std:unique'. Could you help me out with a code snippet if possible?

Comment: Just check out how `std::unique` is implemented - it's all in the header files. It's reasonably straightforward. `std::remove[_if]` use the same approach. The general idea is that you look for elements you want to keep, and copy them over towards the front.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <set>

    int main() {

    std::vector<int> arr1 {3,9,1,2,3,8,13,7,2,9,20,7,4,5,13,1,5,6,2,5,20,13,3,5,6};
    std::vector<int> arr2;
    std::vector<int> frequency;
    std::set<int> uniques;
    int failedCount = 0;

    std::sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end());

    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++)
    {
        auto result = uniques.insert(arr1[i]);

        if(i > 0)
        {
          if(result.second)
          {
            if(failedCount != 0)
            {
                arr2.push_back(arr1[i]);
                frequency.push_back(failedCount +1);
                failedCount = 0;
            }
            else
            {
              arr2.push_back(arr1[i]);

            }

          }
          else
          {
            failedCount++;
          }
        }
        else
        {
          arr2.push_back(arr1[i]);
        }
    }

    frequency.push_back(failedCount +1);

    //print the vectors
    for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "arr1 " << arr1[i] <<std::endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "arr2 " << arr2[i] <<std::endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < frequency.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "frequency " << frequency[i] <<std::endl;
    }

}
```

I use a set to do it in one pass. It is fairly simple that way; Hopefully, a set is fine for you

Answer (score 0):

How about doing the loop during sorting process. The sorting process also has loops. That way  the loop within the sort can be used to do the work. 
This can be done during the last stage/round of the sorting algorithm . 
Sorting algorithms itself do different steps during at different iterations of the sorting process. ( merging of different sorting algorithms to take advantage of different algorithms )

The code below assumes that the sorting used is a kind of merge and that two half of the sorted list are generated .[ this is done to avoid re-writign the whole algo itself)] .
Once the two half are got they are merged . During the merge process additional comparison `a[i] == a[j]` and loops to remove duplicates are added.

These checks were anyway done during the next loop/processing block ( one / two loop ) which we are hoping to optimize. This way those loops can be eliminated and this loop run only for n/2.

One disadvantage of this is it puts the size into a different array size_sz. [ not sure we could do without it. ]

```
#inlude <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count_i  = 1 , count_j = 1 ,check = 0 , count_prev;
    std::vector<int> arr1 {3,9,1,2,3,8,13,7,2,9,20,7,4,5,13,1,5,6,2,5,21,13,3,5,6};
    std::vector<int> arr2,arr_sz;

    //merge sort to produce two sections. These two are merged in the final run.
    sort(arr1.begin(), arr1.end()-arr1.size()/2);
    sort(arr1.end()-arr1.size()/2, arr1.end());

    printf("Sorted array: d\n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr1.begin() ; it != arr1.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';
      //Final merged sort also - modified to remove duplicates and produce count.
     int i , j ;
    for(i = 0,j=(arr1.size()/2)+(arr1.size()%2); i < (int)(arr1.size()/2)&& j < (int)(arr1.size()); )
    {
        // check for duplicates - half 0
        while ( i < (int)(arr1.size()/2-1) && arr1[i] == arr1[i+1] ) {count_i++;i++;}
        // check for duplicates - half 1
        while ( j < (int)(arr1.size()-1) && arr1[j] == arr1[j+1] ) {count_j++;j++;}
        if ( arr1[i] == arr1[j] ) {
             arr2.push_back(arr1[i]) ;
             arr_sz.push_back(count_i+count_j);
           i++;j++ ;count_i=1;count_j=1;
}
else if ( arr1[i] < arr1[j] ) {
     arr2.push_back(arr1[i]) ;
     arr_sz.push_back(count_i);
     i++ ; count_i=1;
}
else if ( arr1[i] > arr1[j] ) {
      arr2.push_back(arr1[j]) ;
      arr_sz.push_back(count_j);
      j++ ; count_j = 1;
};
    }

  // after merge check for left over fields in half 0
    for(; j < (int)(arr1.size()-1);j++ )
     {
        if ( arr1[j]  == arr1[j+1] ) count_j++;
        else {
             arr2.push_back(arr1[j]) ;
             arr_sz.push_back(count_j);
             count_j = 1; }
     }
     if ( j < (int)(arr1.size()) ) {
             arr2.push_back(arr1[j]) ;
            arr_sz.push_back(count_j);
      }
 // after merge check for left over fields in half 1
    for(; i < (int)(arr1.size()/2-1); i++)
     {
        if ( arr1[i]  == arr1[i+1] ) count_i++;
        else {
             arr2.push_back(arr1[i]) ;
             arr_sz.push_back(count_i); count_i= 1;}
     }
     if ( i < (int)(arr1.size()/2) ) {arr2.push_back(arr1[i]) ; arr_sz.push_back(count_i); }

    printf("Sorted unique array: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr2.begin() ; it != arr2.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    //assert(arr1.size() == arr2.size());
    printf("Sorted unique array element frequency: \n");
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = arr_sz.begin() ; it != arr_sz.end(); ++it)
         std::cout << ' ' << *it;
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
 }
```

Some more optimization can be implemented if the basic premises is okay , those should be similar to what merge sort uses. If we go for say quick sort the conditions to check will change but the basic idea will remain the same.